# How can I schedule a laravel task on a specific day of the month?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.1

Now reading through the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling) I don't see a direct function for that, but I do see the option to use the `monthly()` method combined with a `when()` method, so I thought, could I do this maybe:

```
$schedule->command('send:reminders')->monthly()->when(function() {
    return date('d') == '23';
});
```

But now I'm afraid that won't work, because as far as I can see it will try the `when()` constraint only once a month (probably not on the date that I want it to) and then when it fails it skips that month. At least that's what I'm guessing from reading the source of laravel.

So then I'm lost, how do I make this happen?

Comment: Might not be the cleanest way but if you change `monthly` to `daily` keep then `when` condition I think that will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way might be to make use of the [`cron`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_cron) method so in your case

```
$schedule->command('send:reminders')->cron('0 0 23 * *');
```

That is saying run at midnight on the 23rd day of the month.

Comment: Just a little update, from laravel 5.2.23 onwards [monthlyOn](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_monthlyOn) is available.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the default function that is given in laravel scheduling

`public function frequency(\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event $event){
        $event->monthlyOn(24, '17:00');
 }`

monthlyOn(Date,'Time');

This scheduler will run on 24th of every month at 5pm.